# How to modify a file name within a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a shell script to sync to a github repo, kick off the build, then take the output file, rename it, and move it to a location where it can be seen by Apache.

It's the renaming of the file that I've got not the faintest how to do within a shell script (I have virtually no experience with shell scripts - my understanding

Compiler will create /var/espbuild/firstpart_1vXX_secondpart.bin

I need to move this file to:

/var/www/html/builds/espbuild/firstpart_1vXX_DATE_secondpart_postfix.bin

1vXX is the version number

DATE is the output of date +%m-%d

postfix is just a string.

I'm not really certain where to start for something like this - I'm sure there's a graceful way, since this is the kind of thing shell scripts are made for, but I know just about nothing about shell scripts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there likely to be more than one such `*.bin` file in that directory? If so are the rest of them allowed to be moved to that web directory also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the result of a command into a variable by using `$()`:

```
DATE=$(date +%m-%d)
```

Then just use it in the new filename:

```
INPUT=/var/espbuild/firstpart_1vXX_secondpart.bin
OUTPUT=/var/www/html/builds/espbuild/firstpart_1vXX_${DATE}_secondpart_postfix.bin
mv ${INPUT} ${OUTPUT}
```

Edit:  To get out the version part, here's a quick example:

```
VERSION=$(grep -o 1v.. <<< ${INPUT})
```

Then `OUTPUT` should be set like:

```
OUTPUT=/var/www/html/builds/espbuild/firstpart_${VERSION}_${DATE}_secondpart_postfix.bin
```

Comment: Thanks - but how do I deal with the 1vXX part? That could be "1v65" today, "1v66" tomorrow, etc - this is the part that I was most stuck on.

Comment: Thanks - but still, I don't know how to get the value of input, because the file name is not constant.  I thought I could just do something like ls /var/espbuild  | grep firstpart_1v\d\d_secondpart.bin  - but this isn't working, and I'm not sure why - shouldn't the \d's match anything that follows that pattern with two digits there?

Comment: Make sure the `\d` is escaped properly; the shell might eat the backlash otherwise.  `grep 'firstpart_1v\d\d_secondpart.bin'` would be safe, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in BASH:

```
f='/var/espbuild/firstpart_1vXX_secondpart.bin'
s="${f##*/}"
s2=${s##*_}
dest="/var/www/html/builds/espbuild/${s%_*}_$(date '+%m-%d')_${s2%.*}_postfix.bin"

echo "$dest"
/var/www/html/builds/espbuild/firstpart_1vXX_07-14_secondpart_postfix.bin

cp "$f" "$dest"
```